# How to run AWS SageMaker lifecycle config scripts as a background job

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to customize Amazon SageMaker Notebook Instances using Lifecycle Configurations because I need to install additional pip packages. What it means is I have to create a `on-start.sh` and `on-create.sh` script within a lifecycle configuration. You can see a sample [here](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-sagemaker-notebook-instance-lifecycle-config-samples/tree/master/scripts/export-to-pdf-enable).

[image]

Now, I have many packages and the installation time might go over 5 minutes, causing a potential timeout. It is suggested to use `nohup` to run the script as a background job in that [case](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-sagemaker-notebook-instance-lifecycle-config-samples/blob/master/scripts/install-pip-package-all-environments/on-start.sh).

But how do I run this with a `nohup` since I do not have a terminal in this case [see above screenshot]? Is there a way to run the script as a background job from within the script? Anything else I am missing? Please suggest

Answer (score 1):

I have done this before, install many libraries for around 15 minutes. I wrapped the script I actually want to run in a create.sh and run that create.sh using nohup. Now the logs of these you can view on cloudwatch and also sagemaker start wont time out with a plus that you will have nohup.out file where you executed the nohup.
Below I wrapped script in https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-sagemaker-notebook-instance-lifecycle-config-samples/tree/master/scripts/export-to-pdf-enable into create.sh

```sh
#!/bin/bash
set -e
cat <<'EOF'>create.sh
#!/bin/bash
sudo -u ec2-user -i <<'EOF'
set -e

# OVERVIEW
# This script enables Jupyter to export a notebook directly to PDF.
# nbconvert depends on XeLaTeX and several LaTeX packages that are non-trivial to
# install because `tlmgr` is not included with the texlive packages provided by yum.

# REQUIREMENTS
# Internet access is required in on-create.sh in order to fetch the latex libraries from the ctan mirror.

sudo yum install -y texlive*
unset SUDO_UID
ln -s /home/ec2-user/SageMaker/.texmf /home/ec2-user/texmf
EOF


echo 'EOF' >> create.sh

nohup bash create.sh &
```

Comment: @nad please check if this helps

Comment: so is this your create.sh script?

Comment: @nad I wrapped the create script from https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-sagemaker-notebook-instance-lifecycle-config-samples/tree/master/scripts/export-to-pdf-enable into create.sh

Comment: I modified a bit, you should get a gist of what I am trying to do

Comment: @nad can you confirm if it helps?